# What is the meaning of ":"?

Tags: java

I have been watching some LinkedList videos to try and understand what it is. But I see a lot of people having code like

```
for(String x : model)
```

Can anyone help me understand what ":" does in this code besides attaching x to "model" or is that all it does?

Comment: just part of foreach loop syntax

Comment: for each string x in model

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Is the **'in'** of a **'for each'**

    for(String x : model)
Can be translated to for each String in model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the loop will iterate through each object of the list

`String x` declares a String named `x`

`model` is the list of String you want to iterate through

`:` is the operator making the compiler doing this operation.

You can read the `for` like this : ***For each `String` in `model`, use x as variable and do the following operations.***

you can then use `x` to do the operations you want on each elements of the list

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `:` literally means **in**.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax of the [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). It marely means that you're iterating over all the elements in `model`, where in each iteration the `String x` is assigned with the current element so you can use in the loop's body.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to mathematical notation that represents elements in a set.

Read left to right; For all string's x that are elements in model, do .